# Why does R set CRS inconsistently?

Tags: coordinate-system, r, sf

I'm running into a situation (using R on MacOS) where sf() is giving different levels of precision on the CRS. This causes problems for geospatial operations, as indicated below with st_crop().

Can anyone explain what's going on here? I'm admittedly puzzled.

Reproducible example:

```
# Download data
download.file("http://sedsh127.sedsh.gov.uk/Atom_data/ScotGov/ZippedShapefiles/SG_UrbanRural_2016.zip", 
              destfile = "data/SG_UrbanRural_2016.zip")
unzip("data/SG_UrbanRural_2016.zip", exdir = "data")

urbanrural_sf <- st_read("data/SG_UrbanRural_2016.shp") %>% st_transform(27700)

download.file("https://borders.ukdataservice.ac.uk/ukborders/easy_download/prebuilt/shape/Scotland_ca_2010.zip", 
              destfile = "data/Scotland_ca_2010.zip")
unzip("data/Scotland_ca_2010.zip", exdir = "data")

admin_lev1_sf <- st_read("data/scotland_ca_2010.shp") %>% st_transform(27700)

centralbelt_region <- st_bbox(c(xmin = 224479.2, xmax = 642963.5,
                      ymin = 347475.0, ymax = 711014.5),
                    crs = st_crs("+init=epsg:27700")) %>% 
  st_as_sfc()
```

Running st_crs shows how an extra decimal of precision is present on the centralbelt_region polygon (scroll to the right to see). Otherwise CRS are exactly the same:

```
> st_crs(centralbelt_region)
Coordinate Reference System:
  EPSG: 27700 
  proj4string: "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.06,0.1502,0.247,0.8421,-20.4894 +units=m +no_defs"
> st_crs(admin_lev1_sf)
Coordinate Reference System:
  EPSG: 27700 
  proj4string: "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.06,0.15,0.247,0.842,-20.489 +units=m +no_defs"
>
```

This causes problems when I try to run:

```
> urbanrural_sf_simplified_centralbelt <- st_crop(urbanrural_sf_simplified, centralbelt_region)
Error in geos_op2_geom("intersection", x, y) : 
  st_crs(x) == st_crs(y) is not TRUE
```

Would be really glad for any insights folk have on this.

Comment: Seems to be a difference in the CRS when you specify as numeric or +init - compare `st_crs(27700)$proj4string` and `st_crs("+init=epsg:27700")$proj4string` - that shows the problem without any data required.

Comment: At an even lower level its a difference between `sf:::CPL_crs_from_proj4string("+init=epsg:27700")` and `sf:::CPL_crs_from_epsg(as.integer(27700))` - these functions then call C code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that `sf` is ultimately delegating this to two different "authorities"...

The differences boil down to this R code before hitting C code:

```
> sf:::CPL_crs_from_proj4string("+init=epsg:27700")
Coordinate Reference System:
  EPSG: 27700 
  proj4string: "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy 
   +towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.06,0.1502,0.247,0.8421,-20.4894 +units=m +no_defs"
> sf:::CPL_crs_from_epsg(as.integer(27700))
Coordinate Reference System:
  EPSG: 27700 
  proj4string: "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy 
  +towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.06,0.15,0.247,0.842,-20.489 +units=m +no_defs"
```

The difference is only in the datum shift parameters:

```
+towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.06,0.1502,0.247,0.8421,-20.4894
+towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.06,0.15,0.247,0.842,-20.489
```

These come from `proj` and `gdal`. `proj` can tell you its datum shift parameters with `proj -ld`:

```
$ proj -ld 
      [...]
      OSGB36 airy         towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.060,0.1502,0.2470,0.8421,-20.4894
```

and `gdal` has them in `/usr/share/gdal/2.2/datum_shift.csv`:

```
$ grep OSGB  /usr/share/gdal/2.2/datum_shift.csv

530,1314,4277,4326,<etc etc> 1264,49.79,60.94,-8.82,1.92,1,0,9606,
  446.448,-125.157,542.06,0.15,0.247,0.842,-20.489,1
```

This shows the same difference in the precision, which is why I think lookup by number is doing one thing and lookup by character is doing the other.

Not sure of the solution though - ultimately the two authorities should be made to agree...

Comment: Thanks for this really detailed breakdown. Makes perfect sense. Though i agree with your conclusion that there shouldn't be inconsistencies in the output. Wondering if I should put up an issue on github for sf()

Comment: Its not an `sf` issue, I suspect Edzer will close it! The problem is only really going to happen if you are inconsistent about assigning CRSs to data.

Comment: So is there an alternate way to build that bbox polygon above which will call sf:::CPL_crs_from_epsg(as.integer()) instead?

Comment: In particular, I'm trying to default to using epsg, as this seems to be increasingly preferred to proj4...

Comment: Given an integer, you could construct the proj4 string via `paste0("+init=epsg:",intepsg)` or similar...

Comment: Just to confirm, as you've suggested changing the line above from: `urbanrural_sf <- st_read("data/SG_UrbanRural_2016.shp") %>% st_transform(27700)
` to `urbanrural_sf <- st_read("data/SG_UrbanRural_2016.shp") %>% st_transform(paste0("+init=epsg:",27700))` resolves this issue:
`> st_crs(urbanrural_sf)
Coordinate Reference System:
  EPSG: 27700 
  proj4string: "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.06,0.1502,0.247,0.8421,-20.4894 +units=m +no_defs"`

Comment: Yes. I was a bit surprised that `st_crs(some integer)` didn't do actually do that under the hood.